Covering a smoke alarm horn
To clarify: the intent is to install a low frequency sounder beside the smoke alarm and use the low frequency sounder to meet the decibel requirements, as this will produce a less piercing tone. NFPA 72 permits fire alarm notification appliances to be used for this purpose.
Therefore, it would be desirable to cover the horn on the smoke alarm so that the majority of the noise comes from the low frequency sounder. Are there any other legal issues in doing so in Maryland (assuming the landlord understands what I am doing and is in agreement), and what would be the best way to do so without interfering with the detection?

Why do you care so much about the pleasantness of your smoke alarm tone?  How is it bothering you?

@jay613   Maybe a bad cook.

A fire alarm should be a piercing tone.  It's designed to be unpleasant — that way, you're more likely to a) hear it, and b) take some rapid action (checking for and fighting the fire if safe, and/or getting out).  The only reasons I can think of for wanting it to be less piercing are if you're getting lots of false alarms (which would need dealing with properly, not making more bearable), or if you want your building to burn down…

@gidds A real consideration in commercial systems is the ability to communicate. For example, one may need to tell incoming fire personnel that somebody is trapped or there's a particular hazard, or letting the floor warden know that the area is clear. That's why commercial sounders often have selectable levels and particularly in places like offices that are not permitted for sleeping and hallways and lobbies, they're adjusted to meet a certain loudness spec and not more.

Consider replacing the whole fire alarm with e.g. Google Nest fire alarm that gives an early "heads up" warning a short time before the standards-specified alarm threshold is reached. This does depend on what kind of alarm is currently installed and whether it connects to a building-wide system. Having a heads-up alarm in addition to the normal alarm would at least reduce the shock from sudden sound.

@crip659 Not necessarily. Whenever I fire up the wok and stir-fry something Chinese, the smoke alarm invariably goes off. It's on a 10-foot ceiling, and I prepare for it by having a fiberglass pole ready to push the button.

Can you get an extractor hood installed? You can get self-contained models that run the air through an activated charcoal filter and do not require an exhaust vent.

@Wastrel change your technique.   It's easy to screw up a stir fry because everything happens so fast, but if it's happening every time you're doing something wrong.  Head over to cooking SE.

@jay613 I think you missed the point. There's nothing wrong with my cooking, but the smoke alarm is an annoyance. My ex-wife is Chinese and she set off the smoke alarm in our house, too, until I disabled it. I sympathize with the OP, but the smoke alarm is supposed to be annoying and he shouldn't try to change it.

No!
You won't just be transforming the tone.  You'll also be transforming the reliability.  A reliable consumer product that has been tested and certified, probably tens of thousands of hours of testing and improvement by people whose careers are dedicated to that!  Designed from standards based on more of the same.
Transforming it into something more like a high school science project with a Radio Shack electronics kit.
Worse, if there are other tenants in your rental building, they would also suffer from the failure of your smoke alarm in a fire.

No, this is possible to do with listed parts (relay kit for the smoke alarm in question + a System Sensor MP120KL and mating LF sounder) -- it just won't work without AC power

@ThreePhaseEel Surely the "won't work without AC power" renders it noncompliant? Perhaps building a battery-backed system with a non-sounder sensor and a separate sensor might be compliant.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica -- it's the same caveat that you get with other supplementary notification devices (such as strobes)

If OP has a modular or commercial system that can accommodate such mods, he should document that in the Question and I would delete this answer.   Without that, the vast majority of residential smoke detectors are not capable of any modifications, and none of them are designed to accept alternate sounding devices by physically muffling the built-in ones.

"landlord" = "you can't do this". The law in many places in the United States restricts you from changing electrical things in a rental: the landlord has to hire an electrician to do it. Also, you can't modify things beyond what UL or ETL saw when they certified it. You'll get a whole heap of trouble if the safety device comes into play one day and these modifications are discovered. Not to mention possibly killing someone or dying yourself, if the alarm fails to alarm correctly.
You will have to find a completely built and UL/ETL-certified smoke alarm that meets your needs and ask the landlord to coordinate putting it in.

Adding something like tape to the outside of a smoke alarm constitutes a modification? Did not know that.
Do any nonlatching conventional system smoke detectors exist? The building has an addressable fire alarm system and speakers in the units but I don't know if there is any SLC wiring in here.

What's reasonable (or seems so) is often very different than what the insurance company or the fire department thinks is OK. They have final say and authority to punish. Also, what seems reasonable can have consequences that cannot be foreseen. If I were you I'd go to a fire alarm company, tell them what's already installed, ask them about my needs about the alarm, and see if they can offer a different suggestion. It could be possible there are UL/ETL-listed alarms for folks with different hearing frequency ranges that can do what you want.

adding paint to the outside of a smoke alarm constitutes a modification.

@DDuck Every smoke alarm I've seen (albeit not in the US) has DO NOT PAINT written on it. Covering with tape, which would impact the sensing ability even more, is surely also out.

Leave the smoke alarm alone. Get a pair of these and keep them on a hook on the wall near the stove or toaster or whatever is making smoke so that you can deal with a smoke condition in comfort.

Image credit: Moldex.com

@jay613 I took it to mean that you put the earplugs in after the alarm has started so that you don't go nuts while letting the smoke out.

@AndrewMorton yes. It does mean that.  Still.  If you are letting smoke out of your house so often that you have special equipment ready to make it more comfortable, something is wrong.

Strange my original comment vanished but the responses to it did not
